# Remove div on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote an autocomplete type thingy that goes through divs and adds them to a list if their name/id is found. I am  using an event handler that I found online that is called on any sort of input change. The issue that I am having is: When a valid div is found and added to the autocomplete list, and then the user continues to type, but is typing an invalid div name, the div name is removed from the list; HOWEVER, if no divs are found, the list persists but is blank.

A better way to explain is to try it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ypz0zrzv/21/

Type "Test Unit" in the box, and then continue to type random letters. I am trying to get the now empty list to remove. The issue is that, when I implement such a feature, it is only going to happen after a second character is entered. This is because the handler checks the list on input change.

So if I type "Test Unit" it adds the div. If  I type "Test Unita" it shows a blank autocomplete div. If I type "test Unitaa" now the autocomplete div will be gone.  I am puzzled how to get the autocomplete to be blank immediately after it has found no divs.

Code problem in question

```
if ($('#autocomplete_list li').length === 0){
    hide_remove($('#autocomplete'))   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check for the auto complete was in the wrong location. It was being triggered by the wrong event.

I moved the check into its own function, in case you want to call this check at a later time:

```
function checkArray(){
    console.log($('#autocomplete_list li').length);
    if ($('#autocomplete_list li').length <= 0){
        hide_remove($('#autocomplete'))   
    }
}
```

Then I added that `checkArray()` function into the `hide_remove()` function.

```
function hide_remove($div){
    if ($div.length > 0){
        $div.slideUp(250, function(){
           $div.remove(); 
            checkArray();
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/ypz0zrzv/26/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But is there some kind of danger in recursion there? hide_remove will call check array, which calls hide remove, etc..

Comment: I see your point, but check the console log. It doesn't appear to be causing recursion, otherwise the console would continue outputting the length of the array.

Comment: Also, I'm sure there is another place you could trigger that function if need be.